# Can the number of samples passed to the explainer affect the shap value results?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

Suppose we have the following code:

```
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(model)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(rec_feat)
```

The model is a lgbm classifier and rec_feat is a single row from the test dataframe. Shap values will be used to generate a single force plot and view the important features of rec_feat.

I am curious to understand the effect of passing a single row versus a subset of the dataframe (approx. 10k) containing rec_feat. Would the shap value change in these two scenarios?

NB: I am not evaluating summary plot, just the local instances.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes, the SHAP values would change when you provide different samples to rec_feat.

The long answer is yes if you are using the TreeExplainer and no if you are using the KernelExplainer. Why? Because the SHAP values are relative to the background dataset. In TreeExplainer, when the background dataset is not provided (which is in your case), the default background dataset is the " number of training samples that went down each tree path as our background dataset (this is recorded in the model object)." per [SHAP documentation](https://shap-lrjball.readthedocs.io/en/docs_update/generated/shap.TreeExplainer.html).

Why does the SHAP values depend on the background dataset? To answer this question, let's walk through the details behind SHAP.

- When initializing the explainer object, SHAP creates an artificial dataset of coalitions. Each coalition is a binary vector representing the permutation of feature combinations, 1 represents a feature being present, and 0 absent. So there are 2^M possible coalitions for M features.
- When calling the explainer computes SHAP values for a sample, SHAP fills in values for this artificial dataset such that present features take original values of that sample, and absent features are filled with a value from the background dataset. Therefore, the SHAP values are relative to the average prediction of the background dataset.